# Have problem to auto create profile after register new user in django the error show this 'Manager' object has no attribute 'created'

Tags: python, django

Django show AttributeError at /ezz/register/ (this is my url)
'Manager' object has no attribute 'created'

**signals.py files**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.created(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py file**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not <s>`.created(…)`</s>, but [**`.create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```